# Canonical way to type absence of property?

Tags: typescript

is there some canonical way to specify a such that a specific property definitely does NOT have appear on it? I've found one way to do this like so:

```
type NoValue<T extends { value?: never, [key: string]: unknown }> = T
type Foo = NoValue<{}> // typechecks fine
type Bar = NoValue<{name: string}> // also typechecks fine
type Baz = NoValue<{ value: string }> // errors, as it should
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if this covers all edge cases. Is there some standard way of doing this?

Comment: Why? This kinda defeats the point…

Comment: I don't know about "canonical"; there's nothing in the official documentation that says so.  Something like `{value?: never}` is more or less what I would do, but there are certainly edge cases.  Like, what do you think about [these situations](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5oxw)?

Comment: An immediate problem is that `undefined | never` amounts to `undefined`, so that anyway that `NoValue` does not capture the intent.  But even a definition that does capture the intent, will give a type `never`, so a type that cannot be instantiated, not a type that itself errors...  I can post some code if needed.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks, good spotting! The `{ value: undefined }` case doesn't bother me too much, and changing the type to `{ value?: never, [key: PropertyKey]: any }` does seem to fix the problem with `Date`.

Comment: @DanielA.White my use case is I want to add methods to a class via interface declaration merging and I want to make sure there are no existing methods with the same name on the class... idk, it seems to me there would be other cases where it would be useful to check that a prop doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, `any` will clear up that bit.  I'd be happy to write up an answer with the caveats that: • there is no "canonical" way to do this, but `{prop?: never}` is a common approach •this can only possibly prevent it from being *known* to exist, since nothing stops aliasing like `const x = {prop: 123}; const y: {} = x; const z: {prop?: never} = y;`, a documented unsoundness with optional properties • there are always edge cases in TypeScript so the only way to know if it works for you is to thoroughly test against use cases. | Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yeah that sounds good, and the aliasing behaviour seems TypeScript-y enough. Tbh I wasn't even fully aware that type assertion would work like this on LHS during assignment (I usually tend to either either infer types or use `as`), but thinking about it now I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see "type assertion" anywhere in my code. Are you talking about [type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables)?  They are not the same as assertions.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant type annotation. Though, that got me interested, what would be the difference in cases like this? E.g. `const x: {} = { prop: 123 }; const y = { prop: 123 } as {};`, isn't either telling the compiler to infer the wider type (`{}`)? 

If you don't have the time to explain, feel free to just write up the original answer, don't want to take up more of your time than I already have. 
`

Comment: Assertions allow narrowing (generally unsafe) as well as widening (generally safe), while annotations only allow widening. If you only widen then there's no real difference, but the way to be sure that you're not accidentally narrowing is to use annotations. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (but I won't talk about annotations-vs-assertions).

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "canonical" way to prohibit specific string literals from appearing as known property keys of an object type in TypeScript, as there is no documented feature that specifically does this.  But what you're doing is probably the "standard" approach.

The closest you can come is to use an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) which allows a property to be missing, whose type is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) which you can't generally find a value of.  The most reasonable way to satisfy `{value?: never}` is with an object that lacks a `value` property.  And if you want to make sure that this is the *only* requirement, then you can add the catch-all [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `{[k: string]: any}`.  You need to use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) instead of [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) because `any` allows [interface types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) without explicit index signatures, while `unknown` does not.  So that gives you

```
type NoValue<T extends { value?: never, [key: string]: any }> = T
```

or

```
function noValue<T extends { value?: never, [key: string]: any }>(t: T) { }

noValue({}); // okay
noValue({ a: 123 }); // okay
noValue({ a: 123, value: 456 }); // error!
// -------------> ~~~~~
```

---

But, as you note, there are edge cases.  The most common one to run into is

```
noValue({ value: undefined }); // okay, usually
```

where `undefined` is considered a valid property type for all optional properties.  You could enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) to prevent this from working, but only at the expense of adding strictness that isn't part of the standard [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  Many people find `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` to be annoying to use.  It's up to you.

---

A less common edge case: you actually *can* sometimes seem to obtain a value of type `never`, as long as it means the compiler is sure that the JavaScript runtime will throw an exception before you get there.  For example:

```
const v = {
    get value(): never {
        throw new Error("I DON'T LIKE YOU")
    }
};
noValue(v); // okay
```

So `v` is seen to be of type `{value: never}` by the compiler.  That's because if you were to actually try to evaluate `v.value`, there would be a runtime exception.  So instead of `undefined` existing at `v.value`, there's a bomb there.  This is very uncommon but technically possible, so ‍♂️.

---

And finally, nothing can stop the compiler from losing track of whether or not a value has a `value` property, because you can always "safely" widen a type to a supertype, and because optional properties are considered assignable to and from a type without a known property.  (See [this comment on ms/TS#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479#issuecomment-767226743) for example).  So that gives you something like

```
const w = { a: 123, value: "abc" };
const x: {a: number} = w; // okay
noValue(x); // okay!
```

where the compiler has explicitly been told to forget about the `value` property on `x`, even though the object definitely has one.  And then `noValue(x)` succeeds because, as far as the compiler knows, `x` has no `value` property.

---

There may be other caveats and edge cases, but these are the main ones.  Basically you need to test against your use cases because for some people these issues are completely harmless, and for others they are showstoppers.  I'd say that all we can really do in TypeScript is to *discourage* an object property, as opposed to really *prohibiting* it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type NothingCanBeAValue = { [K: keyof any]: never };

const iHaveSomeValue: {} = { foo: 42 };

const objectAboveIsAssignableTo: NothingCanBeAValue = iHaveSomeValue;

// no type error
```

There's no way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to type an empty object, but rather an object that can have any number properties except for some specific/named property. But your empty object solution does seem to work: `type Empty = { [key in PropertyKey]: never }; const foo = { name: "Joe" }; const bar: Empty = foo; // type errors`

Comment: @AdamB this only works for object literal.